# MySQL returning results from one table depend on existence of data in another table (master category)

Tags: mysql

I need some advice on how to optimize my query. It is pretty close to the concept of 'coalesce'.

The case is there is a set of products and each product has many properties (color, material, price, etc.) Instead of defining them one by one, I have added a product line to group the product.

Now, I can define the product property in the product line directly and allow the product within the product line to inherit the property.
If certain product has specific property different from the product line, it can be defined separately.

Now I want to optimize the query to exact the product, product line and all its corresponding property

Please refer to this image
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rFT5z_TPnwqeWcd0fA1lrSlsTy-Dlenf

I already have the code that is working but i want to optimize it.
any suggestions?

I have tried a very straightforward method to use UNION and NOT IN .

```sql
select *
from
  (select product_id, mapping.product_line_id, property_type, property_value
   from product
     left join product_and_product_line_mapping on product.product_id = product_and_product_line_mapping.product_id
  ) a 
# get all the product with specifically defined property (most granular)

union

  (select * from (
    select product_id,product_line_id,property_type,property_value
    from product_line
    left join product_and_product_line_mapping on product.product_id = product_and_product_line_mapping.product_id
  ) product_line_property 
# get all the product lines property

    where (product_line_property.product_id) not in # exclude the product id that is already defined 
          (select product_id from product)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your expected result, Its completely unclear what exactly you want but still you may try this -

```
select product_id
      ,mapping.product_line_id
      ,property_type
      ,property_value
from product
left join product_and_product_line_mapping mapping on product.product_id = mapping.product_id
left join product_line_property on product_line.product_id = mapping.product_id
where product_line_property.product_id not in (select product_id from product)
```

Comment: I was looking if there's a way to use "not in" in case this table is large and it will be slow.

Comment: also, your sql still have a problem. the selected "product_id,mapping.product_line_id ,property_type,property_value" is not clearly which table they are from. 
Both "product" and "product line" have property_type, property_value.

That's why I used union to combine them together.